# What does 'n' mean in this program (python)?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, operators

In the sample program below, I tried to find the even number with the the number I typed in (2, 1, 4, 0) these 4 numbers. The result is 2, but I don't know what (n) means in this program.

```
a = int(input())

n = 0

while a != 0:
    if a % 2 == 0:
        n = n + 1
    a = int(input())

print(n)
```

Comment: n is the number of even numbers inputed by the user.

Comment: The user will take input `a`. if `a` is even then it will `count+1` to `n`. if `a==0` then exit the loop and print `n`

Answer (score 0):

here `n` is used to count `even` numbers.

the loop will keep checking whether given input is 0 or not if it is 0 the loop will exit if not it will check whether it is `even` or `odd`, if the number is `even` it will increase the value of n by 1. If you input 10 even numbers the value of n will be `10` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

n is your counter and probably you forgot to make a break from the loop the loop will be an infinite loop you have to add a condetion so that the loop stops like:

`while n != 10 :`

Or

add if statement

`if n < 10 :`

`break #to quit the loop`